# Find document with only expected values allowed in nested array field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'll start with the example as it's easier to explain for me.

```json
[
    {
        "_id": 100,
        "narr": [
            {
                "field": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": 101,
        "narr": [
            {
                "field": 1,
            },
            {
                "field": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Goal is to find document exactly with values specified by me for a `field`.
Example:
for `lookup = [1]` find document with `_id=100`.
for `lookup = [1,2]` find document with `_id=101`.
So far I came up with (for second example with [1,2]):

```py
db.col.find(
    {
        "narr": {
            "$all": [
                {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "field": {
                            "$in": [1, 2]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

But it also includes document with `_id=100`. How can I make it perform strict match?
Building whole arrays won't work as there are multiple fields with unknown values in each nested structure.

Comment: the first is a collection? if it is a collection you dont have a nested array, collections are not like arrays.If the first is an array provide the full document in json if you can

Comment: Why don't simply do a match in `narr.field` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s-f0Bl9OMCb)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without considering duplication in the `field` and your input, you can simply do a find on `narr.field`. It is like performing search on an array with values from `field`.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      "$narr.field",
      [
        1,
        2
      ]
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s-f0Bl9OMCb) for your reference.

If duplication may happens, try to use `$setEquals`.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    "$setEquals": [
      "$narr.field",
      [
        1,
        2
      ]
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kQo0In4Cmwp) for your reference.